# Add multiple class objects from another class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to generate multiple country objects with the similar language object without going through the admin UI.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class World(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Language = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class add_countries(models.Model):
    sub_part1 = ['USA','ENGLAND','AUSTRALIA','CANADA']
    for sub in sub_part1:
        sub = World.country
        World.Language = "English"

add_countries()
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? I'm guessing you're getting some syntax errors to start with. You could have a look at [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: I am not able to see any errors. Nor am I able to see ['USA','ENGLAND','AUSTRALIA','CANADA'] added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for country in ['USA','ENGLAND','AUSTRALIA','CANADA']:
        World.objects.get_or_create(country=country, language='English')
```

You can put above code inside a method and call that.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have a few database entries that are always there, you should probably consider using [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). This would result in these database rows being created when you migrate your database. The basic idea would be something like this:

```
from django.db import migrations

def add_languages(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    World = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'World')
    languages = {'English': ['USA','ENGLAND','AUSTRALIA','CANADA']}
    for language, countries in languages.items():
        for country in countries:
            World.objects.get_or_create(country=country, Language=language)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_languages),
    ]
```

The migration file would be in your app's migrations directory (something like `project_root/yourappname/migrations/0002_insert_languages.py` in this case). Consult the documentation for more information.